# Images in UIWebView doesn't scaleToFit in iOS 10.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an image which I'm loading in a UIWebView. I've set the scaleToFit as YES for webView. Still it doesn't scale to the screen of webView.

This is happening only when I'm running it on iOS 10.3.1. It work fine on older versions.

self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed any constraints on the image? It could be to do with the device size rather than the iOS version?

Just a thought, might be completely wrong...

Comment: webView contains only an image and I'm not giving any constraints.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you load an image into a UIWebView in the first place?

I recommend using UIImageView whenever possible. With this, you can set it's "contentMode" to your preferred setting. If you need a way to load remote images, check out this really popular & easy to use library:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

With the above library loading a remote image is as easy as this:

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iconURL] options:SDWebImageDownloaderHighPriority progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize, NSURL * _Nullable targetURL) {

 } completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL finished) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [yourImageView setImage:image];
     });
 }];
```

Comment: My WebView content can contain sentences, Math equations, Images. So, I need a webView to load that content. I need to include MathJax to show those Math equations. Is there a way we can do that without WebView? Thank you!